# Keeping a user-defined JScript variable after reload?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, cookies, global-variables

In my HTML document, a button is displayed, and it's onclick event is to alert the variable countervar. Another button can be used to bring countervar up using countervar++. Countervar is never defined in the JScript document, because I want countervar to stay how it was last defined by a user. Like I expected, countervar was nil after each reload. Saving browser cookies also would not work, because the same variable has to be displayed to each user who views the document. I'm looking into "global variables" for an answer, but no luck. Help?

Comment: you can save the variable in localStorage and load from localStorage on load. if localstorage is empty you set the variable to 0.

Comment: do you mean global variable for all users, so for the whole web the variable should be the same in real time?

Comment: then you need to use server side script to save the variable on the server. If you want to have real time update for all users you need to use web sockets or long pulling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use localStorage to achieve part of what you want:

```
var counter;

// save to local storage
window.localStorage.setItem("counter", counter);
// you can call this whenever you make changes to the counter variable

// load from local storage
// call it when the page loads
if( window.localStorage.getItem("counter") === null){
    counter = 0;
}
else{
    counter = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("counter"));
}
```

This will allow you to save the variable for one user. If you want to share it between users, it can't be done just using client side scripting. You'll have to have some sort of server storage/database.